# Packaging a Python library

Tags: python, packaging, distutils

I have a few Munin plugins which report stats from an Autonomy database. They all use a small library which scrapes the XML status output for the relevant numbers.

I'm trying to bundle the library and plugins into a Puppet-installable RPM. The actual RPM-building should be straightforward; once I have a `distutils`-produced distfile I can make it into an RPM based on a .spec file pinched from the Dag or EPEL repos [1]. It's the `distutils` bit I'm unsure of -- in fact I'm not even sure my library is correctly written for packaging. Here's how it works:

idol7stats.py:

```
import datetime
import os
import stat
import sys
import time
import urllib
import xml.sax

class IDOL7Stats:
  cache_dir = '/tmp'

  def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

  # ...

  def collect(self):
    self.data = self.__parseXML(self.__getXML())

  def total_slots(self):
    return self.data['Service:Documents:TotalSlots']
```

Plugin code:

```
from idol7stats import IDOL7Stats
a = IDOL7Stats('db.example.com', 23113)
a.collect()
print a.total_slots()
```

I guess I want idol7stats.py to wind up in `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/idol7stats`, or something else in Python's search path. What `distutils` magic do I need? This:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name = 'idol7stats',
  author = 'Me',
  author_email = 'me@example.com',
  version = '0.1',
  py_modules = ['idol7stats'])
```

almost works, except the code goes in `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/idol7stats.py`, not a subdirectory. I expect this is down to my not understanding the difference between modules/packages/other containers in Python.

So, what's the rub?

[1] Yeah, I could just plonk the library in `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages` using RPM but I want to know how to package Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a *package* to do what you want.  You'd need a directory named `idol7stats` containing a file called `__init__.py` and any other library modules to package.  Also, this will affect your scripts' imports; if you put `idol7stats.py` in a package called `idol7stats`, then your scripts need to "`import idol7stats.idol7stats`".

To avoid that, you could just rename `idol7stats.py` to `idol7stats/__init__.py`, or you could put this line into `idol7stats/__init__.py` to "massage" the imports into the way you expect them:

```
from idol7stats.idol7stats import *
```

Comment: Aha! Putting the code into __init__.py looks exactly what I'm after. Thanks!